# iMac won't shut off normally and stays on the loading circle forever

Tags: osx, shutdown, apple

Every time I try to shut down my iMac it just stays on that loading circle forever. The only way I can get it to shut down is by holding down the power button. I checked the system logs (below) and I can't really see anything that could be causing the shutdown to loop forever. Any ideas?

```
Sep 18 06:47:50 Tardis.local GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[3270]: -[KSUpdateCheckAction(PrivateMethods) finishAction] KSUpdateCheckAction found updates: {( )}
Sep 18 06:47:50 Tardis.local GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[3270]: -[KSPrefetchAction performAction] KSPrefetchAction no updates to prefetch.
Sep 18 06:47:50 Tardis.local GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[3270]: -[KSMultiUpdateAction performAction] KSSilentUpdateAction had no updates to apply.
Sep 18 06:47:50 Tardis.local GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[3270]: -[KSMultiUpdateAction performAction] KSPromptAction had no updates to apply.
Sep 18 06:47:50 Tardis.local GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[3270]: -[KSUpdateEngine(PrivateMethods) updateFinish] KSUpdateEngine update processing complete.
Sep 18 06:47:53 Tardis.local com.apple.usbmuxd[1629]: _SendDetachNotification (thread 0x7fff744ab180): sending detach for device d0:23:db:1b:9a:fa@fe80::d223:dbff:fe1b:9afa._apple-mobdev._tcp.local.: _BrowseReplyReceivedCallback got bonjour removal.
Sep 18 06:48:03 Tardis.local com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.removable.unmount' by client '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [3219] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [3219] (100013,0)
Sep 18 06:48:03 Tardis.local com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.removable.unmount' by client '/usr/sbin/diskarbitrationd' [56] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [3219] (100002,0)
Sep 18 06:48:05 Tardis.local webfilterproxyd[3277]: whitelistVerdict: (null) | kitty has no web restrictions | http://init.ess.apple.com/WebObjects/VCInit.woa/wa/getBag?ix=1
Sep 18 06:48:05 Tardis kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(3279) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sep 18 06:48:05 Tardis.local webfilterproxyd[3277]: whitelistVerdict: (null) | kitty has no web restrictions | https://tools.google.com
Sep 18 06:48:05 Tardis.local sandboxd[3279] ([3277]): webfilterproxyd(3277) deny job-creation
Sep 18 06:48:07 Tardis.local GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[3270]: -[KeystoneDaemon logServiceState] GoogleSoftwareUpdate daemon (1.1.0.3659) vending:
        com.google.Keystone.Daemon.UpdateEngine: 1 connection(s)
        com.google.Keystone.Daemon.Administration: 0 connection(s)
Sep 18 06:48:09 Tardis.local com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.removable.unmount' by client '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [3219] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [3219] (100013,0)
Sep 18 06:48:09 Tardis.local com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.volume.removable.unmount' by client '/usr/sbin/diskarbitrationd' [56] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' [3219] (100002,0)
Sep 18 06:48:15 Tardis.local GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[3270]: -[KeystoneDaemon main] GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon inactive, shutdown.
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[277] (com.apple.PackageKit.InstallStatus): Throttling respawn: Will start in 9 seconds
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis.local WindowServer[106]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 85271
Sep 18 06:48:19 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis.local WindowServer[106]: dict count after removing entry for window 0x56c is 0
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[277] (com.apple.unmountassistant.useragent[3300]): Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis.local coreservicesd[68]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435459 (ipc/send) invalid destination port from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=1538
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[277] ([0x0-0x35f35f].com.apple.iTunesHelper[3263]): Exited with code: 1
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis.local coreservicesd[68]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=1589
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[277] (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[3289]): Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis.local WindowServer[106]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 85271
Sep 18 06:48:20 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Sep 18 06:48:20 Tardis.local loginwindow[3076]: DEAD_PROCESS: 3076 console
Sep 18 06:48:20 Tardis.local coreservicesd[68]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationReady to notificationID=1532
Sep 18 06:48:20 Tardis.local airportd[3194]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “Type 40 Tardis”. Bailing on auto-join.
Sep 18 06:48:20 Tardis.local WindowServer[106]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 85271
Sep 18 06:48:20 --- last message repeated 9 times ---
Sep 18 06:48:20 Tardis.local shutdown[3308]: halt by kitty: 
Sep 18 06:48:20 Tardis.local shutdown[3308]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1347976100 852452
```

Comment: How about a shortcut to `forced shutdown`

Comment: Could be waiting for some background/daemon process to exit cleanly?  Try exiting/killing/stopping background services and perhaps try removing network/external storage and see if the shutdown proceeds more smoothly.

Comment: Have you seen http://apple.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at these sys log :

```
Sep 18 06:48:19 Tardis.local coreservicesd[68]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=1589

Sep 18 06:48:20 Tardis.local airportd[3194]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “Type 40 Tardis”. Bailing on auto-join.
```

What I gather from here is that Tardis is the process which is not getting killed. As a result your system is not getting shut down . Do try to remove it manually from command prompt. That probably will help your system to shut itself down.

Comment: But Tardis is the machine that i'm trying to shutdown? How would I remove it? If you need more information let me know. This only started happening when I used little snitch to monitor all outgoing traffic. And when I uninstalled it this started happening, from what i've noticed. It was probably happening before.

Comment: Hi Antonio, do you have any antivirus running on your system . If so, try removing the same. Many of the antivirus' cause problems in MAC . I insist you look at this thread. This one has helped my friend solve his Mac problem(which was similar to yours) . Use this URL :
http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/268170-imac-does-not-shut-down.html

Comment: I don't have any antivirus on my comp. I would like to get one thought. And even when I do an update and the computer restarts by itself, I still have to force shutdown because it just sits there staring at me like it doesn't know what to do next. I still get the perpetually spinning grey circle.

Comment: I had faced this problem, not so long ago on my desktop, which had a windows xp os. Later it turned out that my motherboard is the one  which had the real problem(i had used it for long 4 and 1/2 yrs). It might be that your hardware is causing you this problem. I changed my mother board after suffering from this problem and voila it started working perfectly. I suggest you have it checked up at a nearby service center.

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean install of Tardis. Solved the problem but I wish I knew what the problem was.